# VBA Overflow Error 6 Not really

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

=Count([qty_rec])/Count([sub]) is the control source for a text box.  Format for the control is 'percentage'.  I have also tried 'standard', fixed and leaving it blank.  I suspect the evaluation is comparing apples to oranges.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.txt_percent_received = 0.5 Then
    Me.cbtn_shortage.Visible = False
Else
End If
End Sub
```

I put breakpoint at If and goto to immediate and type ?Me.txt_percent_received

It says 0.5

Why does system think this number is too big?

and why does it work if I step thru the code?

Updated

```
Dim intTemp As Integer
intTemp = Me.txt_percent_received
If intTemp = 0.5 Then
Me.cbtn_shortage.Visible = False
Else
End If
```

Now the error is on intTemp = Me.txt_percent_received

qty_rec and sub are for totaling populated fields.

Comment: When and where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: I don't understand your textbox. Is this a continuous form? What are [qty_rec] and [sub]? Counting controls (?) is a little odd.

Comment: For totaling values you probably want `Sum()` instead of `Count()`

Comment: BTW, when using `Sum()` it seems to work for me. It's still an unusual and perhaps error-prone way to implement things, though.

Comment: What I was trying to do with that is get a line count and a % of those lines that have a value in the qty_rec field.  It does not matter what value just that there is one there.  I am looking to get those from the query right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the effect, and I think what happens here is:

Calculated controls are evaluated after the form has finished loading. If you remove the event code, and open the form, you will notice that the value of `txt_percent_received` is displayed with a slight delay.
You may even notice that at first it displays `#Number!`, and then calculates the value.

But the form events happen before that, so what you get is a division of `0/0`, and this gets runtime error 6 "Overflow".

`1/0` would get error 11 "Division by zero".

You need a different way either to calculate `txt_percent_received`, or to implement your `cbtn_shortage` logic.

Comment: I suspected it was a timing issue.  That is why I tried 'current' rather than load.  I will re- think the flow logic.  Thank you.